# Nothing goes after TypeORM 0.2 to 0.3 in NestJS

Tags: types, nestjs

I have a problem.

In my NestJS project, I updated TypeORM from version 0.2.* to 0.3.* and nothing works anymore.

```js
/**
* Get all addresses of the user
*
* @param user User
*/
sync getAddresses(user: User): Promise<Address[]> {
 return this.addressRepository.find({
   where: { user: user.id }, // ERROR HERE
 });
}
```

> TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean |
> FindOperator  | FindOptionsWhere  | FindOptionsWhere [] |
> EqualOperator '.

Do you have a solution to this? Or should I go back to the previous version?

Answer (score 3):

There are many changes in typeORM 0.3. Apparently you need the Equal-Operator, especially for scalar values.

Assuming, that `user`-property is an integer storing the ID of a user, try this:

```
import { Equal, Repository } from "typeorm";

return this.addressRepository.find({
   where: { user: Equal(user.id) }, 
 });
```

(This does NOT work for relations and entities)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are using at least *@nestjs/typeorm* 8.1.0.
TypeORM 0.3 is not compatible with 0.2, that is why the nest module should be updated.

> v8.1.0 uses typeorm v0.3+ instead of v0.2+

https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/releases/tag/8.1.0

Comment: I have complied with this update. And yet, nothing works. I still have this error.
```"@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.1.0",
"typeorm": "^0.3.7"
```